# How to manage shared expenses with double entry

Tags: double-entry

I am struggling to find a good answer but I didn't.(spent over 40 hours thinking it). I know that there is a similar question here [Link](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7101/how-to-keep-control-of-shared-expenses-inside-marriage) but it doesn't solve my problem.
How would you manage shared expenses if portions are not equal?
For example if rent is 500 and one pays 400 and other one 100, then it is not 50% so balancing makes no sense. The only solution I found is by adding liabilities/reimbursements. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to use double-entry accounting? And is your partner on board? I have asked this of everyone with a question like this and none have ever answered me. As an accountant I see zero benefit to doing this, only additional confusion. Let alone for someone with a non-accounting background doing it. I am imagining setting up an "inter-company payable/receivable account" with my wife, and it makes me giggle.

Comment: I'm going to agree on asking "Why?", though I do use double-entry in Gnucast for my family's expenses. What kinds of reporting are you hoping to get from this system? Is "[How separate individual expenses from family expenses in Gnucash?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/80458/42405)" helpful?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon No it is only me. I am using it because seems nicer and more clean. I mean using software like gnucash/ledger etc. I did use ledger for a month and in order to handle these and had no big problem.

Comment: @GorillaApe Thanks for the response. Did you previously track your budget in any meaningful way? Does this new system have any meaningful benefits that you want to retain?

Comment: @GorillaApe: If it's only your books, then if your rent expense is $100, why wouldn't you just track that like any other expense? What are you trying to track for the portion you're not responsible for?

Answer (score 3):

It's still not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but I'll do my best.

You say that you're tracking your books "for only me", which means that your books are just reflecting what you earn and spend from your perspective. If you pay $100 for rent and your roommate pays $400 for rent (which is what I think you're trying to say), then even if there's $500 total, your books would only show a $100 transfer from `Assets:Checking` to `Expenses:Rent` or the like. The $400 your roommate spends wouldn't show up at all, since it's not impacting you.

So, the only way I think you may be thinking that you should see it is if in fact one of you actually writes a $500 check to the landlord for rent, and the other pays their portion directly to the other. If you're paying the roommate for your portion, then again it's just a simple transfer from `Assets:Checking` to `Expenses:Rent`, even though the "payee" is your roommate. That's who you're paying for the service, and so that's what the transaction is.

If on the other hand, you pay $500 to the landlord, and then your roommate pays you back $400, then their payment to you is just a negative expense (or rebate) of the Rent that you paid.

Here's the simplest way to represent those two transactions:

```
Memo            Account                       Debit     Credit
------------    -----------------------       --------  --------
Payment to Landlord
                Assets:Checking                          $500.00
                Expenses:Rent                  $500.00

Reimbursement from Roommate
                Assets:Checking                          $400.00
                Expenses:Rent                  $400.00
```

If the two transactions are close enough to each other in time, that's probably good enough. But if it might take a while before your roommate pays you back, and you're not a fan of your records saying you've paid more rent that you're "supposed to have", you could represent what your roommate owes you as an asset (which is probably more accurate, if you've spent money on their behalf and thus they owe you money):

```
Memo            Account                       Debit     Credit
------------    -----------------------       --------  --------
Payment to Landlord
                Assets:Checking                          $500.00
                Expenses:Rent                  $100.00
                Assets:Roommate Owes Me        $400.00

Reimbursement from Roommate
                Assets:Checking                          $400.00
                Assets:Roommate Owes Me        $400.00
```